# Is chef suitable for deployment to various environments?

Tags: deployment, chef-infra

I heard a lot about chef as a configuration manager or to install and update servers but not much about deployment and pre+post steps related to the latter.

I want the following on a couple of in-house linux server:

```
for environments in "env1 env2"
    for services in "service1 service2"
        for nodes in "node1 node2"
            stop service in the fashion of $service
            check if service is really stopped
            download new package
            install new package in path
            update configuration files acording to $environment
            start service
            poke healthcheck to see if deployed
            execute test suite
            if deployed
                go to next node
            else
                fail
```

How much this can be done without hacking around too much?

Is it a suited usage for chef or not that much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chef does everything inside the loop, the loop itself isn't something Chef would handle but it can dovetail nicely with an orchestration tool like Fabric or RunDeck.

Comment: but would this be a smart choice? Is chef the best option when it comes to acheive that kind of work?

Regarding rundeck, I am already using it to kick the script that is currently achieving the deployments. So rundeck would basically do the same with chef.

Comment: Chef is best suited to tasks that are convergence-based, less so to procedural stuffs. So the deploying new code, writing config files, installing services, that's all convergent and Chef can do nicely. Stuff like running the test suite is less so, since that is just running a thing. You can do some level of non-convergent behavior from Chef, but plain RunDeck might be better there.

Comment: Another thing I am wondering. Is chef good at giving feedback? I mean, if things are done as in my example loop, can instructions run on remote node give real time feedback in a efficient fashion?

Comment: Try it and see? It outputs info on each resource as things are processed.